# How do I incorporate into the definition of a function that its output is constant?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, surfaces

Say I have a surface, x-y+xy+yz+z^2 = 0

(There is nothing particulary special about this expression.  I've just made it too complicated to be simplified so that the variables are independent of one another)

Say I want to find all places on that function where x is constant. How do I find the equivalent to fx?  (note that this is a surface, not a function.  in other words it has a constraint that it always equals 0)

Comment: What do you mean by "places where $x$ is constant"?

Comment: When a plane tangent to this surface would be parallel to the y-z axis?

Answer (score 0):

Let the left hand side of the equation defining your surface be denoted $F(x,y,z)$. The set of points where the plane tangent to the surface is parallel to the $y$-$z$ axis is the solution set of the triple of equations
$$F(x,y,z)=0, \qquad \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0, \qquad \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=0
$$

In your example, these three equations are
$$x - y + xy + yz + z^2=0, \qquad -1+x+z=0, \qquad y + 2z = 0
$$
the solution set of which is easily found by substitution.